# Not able to parse the remainder in django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ songname }}</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    {% load static %}
</head>
<body>
    <center><h1>MUOSIC</h1></center>
    <hr>
    <audio controls>
    <source src="{% static {{ songname }} %}" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    <hr>
</body>
```

Here songname is the name of the song which i want to play.All the static files are in the static directory.From the view function the above template is called using render_to_response function.So please can anyone explain the reason for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't nest template variables like that. Assuming that your `songname` is the actual name of the file and the file is in the root of your `STATIC_ROOT`, you simply do:

```
{% static songname %}
```